# Open source 3D model viewer for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, 3d

I'm looking for something like [open3mod](http://www.open3mod.com/), but for Linux. Hopefully something that supports `.ac` files.

I know about g3dviewer, however I can't get it to compile on Arch Linux.

Comment: I think 3D file viewer or 3D model viewer might help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `.ac` files are, but besides g3dviewer there's also the free [view3dscene](http://castle-engine.sourceforge.net/view3dscene.php) which [seems to support quite some formats](http://castle-engine.sourceforge.net/view3dscene.php#section_features).

There also exist the free 3D viewers lookat from [OpenVRML](http://openvrml.org/) and [white_dune](http://vrml.cip.ica.uni-stuttgart.de/dune/), but AFAICS they only support VRML.

Comment: Currently your answer is little more then some links and "this could work". We try to have our recommendations to be personal in nature. Did you use the tools? If so, what are your experiences? Which one does excel at what its doing? Please, do elaborate more on this. Und schöne Grüße nach #plant :)

Answer (score 2):

Blender has a python mod to load **ac** files.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Export/AC3D

Assuming the **ac** file type isn't used by another app.

Comment: That script is for an old version of blender (an updated version can be found [here](https://github.com/majic79/Blender-AC3D)). The thing is, I was actually hoping to find a viewer for the purpose of previewing files before importing into blender. Being written in python, the blender importer is rather slow on large files. When I have a bunch of files to go through this is rather a pain..